# Add multiple lines to a LinearLayout in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-linearlayout

In my app, I have a button that when pressed, displays an AlertDialog with the question to add an entry with two NumberPickers, one for Minutes and the other for seconds. I would like to display a TextView with "Min" above the minutes one, and one with "Sec" above the seconds one. The Java file looks like this:

```java
//create linearlayout for display on the alertdialog
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);
parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

//create upper and lower LinearLayout
LinearLayout upper = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout lower = new LinearLayout(this);
upper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
lower.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

//create parameters for the lower and upper linearLayouts
LinearLayout.LayoutParams upParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams downParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

//Create numberPicker and TextView for the Seconds
final NumberPicker secondsPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
secondsPicker.setMinValue(MIN_SECOND_INPUT);
secondsPicker.setMaxValue(MAX_SECOND_INPUT);

final TextView secondsText = new TextView(this);
secondsText.setText(R.string.Seconds);

//Create numberpicker and TextView for the minutes
final NumberPicker minutesPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
minutesPicker.setMinValue(MIN_MINUTE_INPUT);
minutesPicker.setMaxValue(MAX_MINUTE_INPUT);
final TextView minutesText = new TextView(this);
minutesText.setText(R.string.Minutes);

//create parameters for the LinearLayout
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

//create parameters for the TextView for seconds
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsTextSec = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
paramsTextSec.weight = 1;

//create parameters for the TextView for minutes
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsTextMin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
paramsTextMin.weight = 1;

//create parameters for the numberpicker for the seconds
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsSeconds = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
paramsSeconds.weight = 1;

//create parameters for the numberpicker for the Minutes
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsMinutes = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
paramsMinutes.weight = 1;


//add parameters to linear layout
parent.setLayoutParams(params);
upper.setLayoutParams(upParams);
lower.setLayoutParams(downParams);
upper.addView(secondsPicker, paramsSeconds);
upper.addView(secondsText, paramsTextSec);
lower.addView(minutesPicker, paramsMinutes);
lower.addView(minutesText, paramsTextMin);
parent.addView(upper);
parent.addView(lower);

//create alertdialog with the linear layout with numberpickers
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Add an extra slot:");
builder.setView(parent);
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        int seconds = secondsPicker.getValue() + minutesPicker.getValue() * 60;
        addValueToScheme(seconds);
   }
});
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

The AlertDialog gives a result where the Seconds appear next to the NumberPicker and the NumberPickers appear under each other.

[image: AlertDialog Not Fitting]

How can I add the NumberPickers next to each other with the text above them?

Answer (score 0):

first of all: please, move this Java code do XML, it would be much more easier to read, design and develop...

add `weight=1` for `upParams` and `downParams`

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams upParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
upParams.weight = 1;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams downParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
downParams.weight = 1;
```

this will cause `LinearLayout upper` to be on the left and `LinearLayout lower` on the right (thanks to `parent` orientation `HORIZONTAL`), so change their names... then set their orientation for `VERTICAL`

```
upper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
lower.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

and now you have two vertical containers, left and right, with equal width, and you can add to both some elements, e.g. at first `TextView`, after that `NumberPicker`, both with width `MATCH_PARENT` to fulfil (half of width of whole `Dialog`)